# MikroTik on HP ProLiant DL360 G6

Tags: hp-proliant, mikrotik

Has anybody installed MikroTik RouterOS v4.4 on DL360 G6 server?

Thanks.

Comment: The biggest issue you might run into is lack of support for anything other than direct IDE or SATA drive connections (or USB) at this point in time.

We've previously had to specifically request servers with no SAS backplane so we could get direct connections, alternatively in most cases you can a) remove the backplane or b) run it up inside an ESXi 4 install which gives you an extra layer of access to the system.

Answer (score 1):

No experience sorry but given 4.4 runs on a fairly basic 2.6 linux kernel I wouldn't worry too much. You certainly won't run into any CPU, memory or BIOS issues, the worst problems you might have to get around is finding a disk controller driver depending on which model you have and potentially a NIC driver, but the latter is less likely as they tend to use fairly common chipsets.

So no experience sorry but hopefully some encouragement to get on with it and try! :)

Comment: My only comment is that sometimes high-end HP servers have custom chipsets that tune IRQ handling to favour the disk controllers, which can cock up some low-level functionality.  I first came across this when trying to fit a ISDN PRI card to a DL320

Comment: I tend to keep to fully supported hardware and OS's on my HP boxes so haven't seen this problem but that's a very interesting observation thanks.